# Detecting a development App Server in Go, without the App Engine standalone SDK?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, gcloud, golang-migrate

The Go package, [google.golang.org/appengine](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine), provides [IsDevAppServer](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine#IsDevAppServer) which reports whether an App Engine app is running in the development App Server (e.g. `localhost:8080`). However, this does not work unless the ([deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences)) standalone SDK is used. See [appengine.go#L57](https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/16bce7d3dc4e458f2f6f56a1349cbbfcdc8a8fdf/appengine.go#L57) for the implementation.

New GAE apps written in Go are basically a regular web server that can be compiled and started locally like any go program;

- **old;** `dev_appserver.py`
- **new;** `go run main.go`

Detecting a development server can be useful for to prevent CORS issues when running locally:

```golang
func setDevHeaders(w http.ResponseWriter) {
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Request-Method", "POST, GET")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition")
}
```

When needed I can then branch:

```golang
if appengine.IsDevAppServer() {
    setDevHeaders(w)
}
```

What is the recommended way to achieve this in a standalone Go server running on App Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Engine Standard Go environnement sets a number of environment variables automatically. You can have a look at the list [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/runtime#environment_variables).

You can check if they are set and if they **aren't**, then your code is running locally (or at least not deployed). Or you can set the `NODE_ENV` environment variable to `development` on your machine (in your shell where you run your app locally, not in the app.yaml file) and check for its value. It'll be set to `production` when running on App Engine.

Comment: The server is not run in the App Engine Standard Go environment when started with `go run main.go` - it's just a regular web server.

Comment: Exactly. So unless you define them explicitly yourself in your local environment, these environment variables **won't** be set. So if your code tries to retrieve them and they **aren't** set, then it knows it's running in your local environment, otherwise it's been deployed and is running in App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds tricky but I found that metadata server also respond to app engine standard.

Furthur, I used `cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata` pacakge,

```
metadata.OnGCE()
```

as a quick check whether it is in my local machine or on google's machine (yeah, it returns true on app engine)